# Find common rows from a given range of rows in excel

Tags: excel

So I have to clean data where from a given range of rows maybe 2 or 3 are exact same, rest have at least one column different. I need a way to find it out as I don't want to do it manually. I've tried conditional formatting but that only works with columns.
In the image you can see rows 550:569 a few of them are exactly same. How do I highlight or find out that. I don't want to manually check each column
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrEcj.png)

Comment: Excel has "Remove Duplicates" functionality.

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert a column (let's say column AG) where you put a formula like  =TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A2:AF2)
2. Sort the range per the new column
3. Eliminate duplicate using Excel's Remove Duplicate tool.

Comment: I need to remove duplicate rows from a given range of rows. how do I know which ones are duplicate

Comment: Have you tried the steps above? What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I did the 1st bit where it concatenated all the column values in the AG column. Didn't get what to do after that?

Comment: Got it. I highlighted the duplicates in the new column using conditional formatting. Thanks mate!

Comment: @ShantanuYadav If this answers your question, please mark it as the answer.